# Decomposing a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, information-theory

Note: this question is a *duplicate* of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150224/constructive-proof-for-a-problem-of-discrete-random-variables) asked by my classmate with much more contexts. Attempt to suggest edits is rejected due to drastic change, so I reask the question.

---

I hate to admit it, but I'm asking for help on a homework problem assigned in our *Information Theory* class. I'm really scratching my head but unable to prove it:

> For two discrete random variables $X, Y \sim p(x,y)$, we can find another random variable $Z$ independent of $X$, such that there exists a function $f$ satisfying $Y = f(X,Z)$.

The problem also comes with a hint that calls for a constructive proof.

Now that I have (maybe in a wrong way) constructed a random variable $Y'$ that has the same distribution as $Y$, but I simply can't prove that $Y = Y'$ due to their identical distribution.

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827330/representing-random-variables-in-a-shared-and-private-decomposition) I found may be related to the problem but it goes unanswered. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my professor's answer here. The problem is called Functional Representataion Lemma and you may search for its proof on the internet. The conclusion of the lemma is actually stronger, though.

Answer (score 0):

Given
 $X = x$ and $Y = y$, let $Z$ be uniform on the interval $\left[\mathbb P(Y < y \mid X=x), \mathbb P(Y \le y \mid X = x)\right]$.  Then $Y = \min \{y: \mathbb P(Y \le y \mid  X) \ge Z\}$.  That is, when $X = x$ and $Z = z \in (0,1)$, $Y = \min \{y: \mathbb P(Y \le y \mid X = x) \ge z \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z$ be uniform on $[0,1]$. Given $X=x$, use [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate $Y$, using $Z$ as the uniform variable and using $q(y)= p(x,y)/\left(\sum_y p(x,y)\right)$ as the distribution.

Comment: If I undestand inverse transform sampling correctly, I can recover a random variable by the inverse of its CDF, so is this just an alternative way of constructing a random variable with same distribution as $Y$?

Comment: Yes. If $F$ is a cdf, and $Z\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$, then the random variable $W$ defined by $W=\min\{w\in\mathbb R:F(w)\ge Z\}$ will have $F$ as its cdf. Here, we are using this to construct a random variable whose distribution is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $\{X=x\}$. So, letting $F_x(y)=P(Y\le y|X=x)$, the formula for $Y$ is $$Y=\min\{y\in\mathbb R:F_x(y)\ge Z\}.$$

Comment: Oh I see the problem; I have constructed something which is equal in distribution to $Y$, but not equal to $Y$. Let me think more.@skyfiretimes

Comment: Yep, that's the difficult part about this problem. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: I do not think $f(X,Z)=Y$ is possible, only $f(X,Z)\stackrel{d}=Y$. Consider this small example; there are three cards with the labels $(0,0),(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Choose a random card; $X$ is the first coordinate, $Y$ is the second. In order to have $Y=f(X,Z)$, you need $Z$ to be a function of which card was picked. But that probability space is so small, that there does not even exist a random variable $Z$ which is independent of $X$ (except $Z$ constant).  @skyfiretimes